# One table or many?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm  trying to design an application to hold academic reference information. The problem is that each different type of reference (eg. journal articles, books, newspaper articles etc) requires different information. For example a journal reference requires both a journal title and an article title, and also a page number, whereas a book requires a publisher and a publication date which journal articles do not require.

Therefore, should I have all the references stored in one table in my database and just leave fields blank when they don't apply, or should I have various tables such as BookReferences, JournalReferences, NewspaperReferences and put the appropriate references in each one. The problem then would be that it would make searching through all the references rather more difficult, and also editing would have to be done rather more separately probably.

(I'm planning to use Ruby on Rails for this project by the way, but I doubt that makes any difference to this design question)

**Update:**

Any more views on this? I hoped to get a simple answer saying that a particular method was definitely considered 'the best' - but as usual things aren't quite as simple as this. The Single-Table Inheritance option looks quite interesting, but there isn't much information on it that I can find very easily - I may post another question on this site about that.

I'm split between [Olvak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200394/one-table-or-many#200406) and [Corey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200394/one-table-or-many#200671). Corey's answer gives a good reason why Olvak's isn't the best, but Olvak's answer gives good reasons why Corey's isn't the best! I never realised this could be so difficult...

Any further advice much appreciated!

Comment: I really like this question, thank you. I've been thinking over a similar problem with regard to a Product table in an e-commerce setting and the answers here can easily apply to that. Cheers.

Comment: Just wondering: how many records are you expecting to have? Obviously just a ballpark figure. I think that should also be a factor in the final decision.

Comment: If you're struggling between Olvak and Corey's answers take a look at the votes. Having worked with DBs for 15 years I prefer Olvak's solution by a mile. The votes seem to indicate it's the correct approach too.

Comment: @Tom H: Good point. I was definitely leaning towards his solution

Comment: @nickf: Great question - problem is that I don't really know. There will definitely be hundreds of different references in there (just to support my own personal use), but I'm planning on having this as a public webapp so it could take off in a crazy way (we can always hope!)

Answer (score 36):

I'd go for having a single table for all references, but additional tables like BookReferences and so on for metadata not applicable for all reference types.

Searching and querying would not be more difficult - after all you could just create a view which aggregates all information as in the single-table solution, and then query that view further.

Having everything in one table with lots of nulls might seem like the simpler solution, but actually it will lead to lots of trouble. For example: With separate tables you can define which fields are *required* for every BookReference, but if everything is in one table, every field has to be nullable and therefore optional. It would also be easier to insert invalid data, like a book reference which also erroneously contains a non-null journal name.

Edit: Some people seem to fear joins. *Don't fear the join!* If you use the exact same join in several queries that would indeed be tedious, but in that case the join should be defined in a *view*, and you queries should query that view. Views are really the basic abstraction in relational databases, and you should use them for the same reasons you use functions in code: to avoid repetition, and to encapsulate and create abstractions.

Edit: There are some comments regarding performance. It's very hard to guess beforehand about performance of DB schemas, because it is often non-intuitive. For example a join between several tables can easily be faster than a full table scan of a single table - it all depends on the type of query, the nature of the data, the available indexes and so on. Additionally, in many database systems you can use features like materialized views to optimize performance for different queries without compromising the logical model. "Denormalization for performance" is mostly cargo cult these days IMHO, unless you are Google or Flickr.

Comment: You took the words out of my hands, thief! :)

Comment: The Document Management approach (used by Documentum, for instance)

Comment: How would I link to the other tables? For example if record 1 in my Reference table was a Book reference and therefore linked to a record in the BookReference table, how would I know to look there for it rather than in the JournalReference table?

Comment: Two options:  1) Check all the other tables to see which (if any) are linked to Reference #1.  2)  If a Reference can only ever be of one type, you could add a field which indicates which type each record is.

Comment: I agree with this design.  BookReferences would include a foreign key to the parent References table.  This does allow multiple sub-tables to reference the same row in the parent table, but it's still the best compromise.

Answer (score 9):

"life is easier with the one big table": I've seen the natural consequence of this, being a 100+ column table, and I can tell you I find this no joy to work with.

The main problem is that the designers of such tables tend to omit the constraints required to ensure data integrity. For example, the OP says:

> a journal reference requires both a journal title and an article title, and also a page number, whereas a book requires a publisher and a publication date which journal articles do not require

...which implies the following constraints:

```
CONSTRAINT a_journal_must_have_a_journal_title
   CHECK ( type <> 'journal' OR journal_title IS NOT NULL );

CONSTRAINT a_journal_must_have_an_article_title 
   CHECK ( type <> 'journal' OR article_title IS NOT NULL );

CONSTRAINT a_journal_must_have_a_page_number 
   CHECK ( type <> 'journal' OR page_number IS NOT NULL );

CONSTRAINT a_journal_cannot_have_a_publisher 
   CHECK ( type <> 'journal' OR publisher IS NULL );

CONSTRAINT a_journal_cannot_have_a_publication_date 
   CHECK ( type <> 'journal' OR publication_date IS NULL );

CONSTRAINT a_book_cannot_have_a_journal_title 
   CHECK ( type <> 'book' OR journal_title IS NULL );

CONSTRAINT a_book_cannot_have_a_article_title 
   CHECK ( type <> 'book' OR article_title IS NULL );

CONSTRAINT a_book_cannot_have_a_page_number 
   CHECK ( type <> 'book' OR page_number IS NULL );

CONSTRAINT a_book_must_have_a_publisher 
   CHECK ( type <> 'book' OR publisher IS NOT NULL );

CONSTRAINT a_jbook_must_have_a_publication_date 
   CHECK ( type <> 'book' OR publication_date IS NOT NULL );
```

...and I suspect that's only the tip of the iceberg!

It's my hope that after writing several hundred such constraints the designer may have second thoughts about all those nullable columns :)

Answer (score 7):

My advise is to start by designing the database properly, that is using normalisation to ensure tables only contain data about one thing (book, journal, etc.) and that attributes are stored in the right table.

If in the future it creates performance problems you can de-normalise it into less tables, but this is unlikely to be a problem unless you have a huge database.

Create one table that will hold the common attributes for all references.

Create separate tables to hold the attributes that are specific to each type of reference.

The other issue is whether you will have many references to a single work,e.g. hundreds of references to a particular journal. Normalisation would then suggest you have a table that holds the journals (title, author,journal), a table that holds the reference information that is specific to journals (article, page), and another table that holds data that is common to all references (date of reference, type of reference).

Comment: Oooh! Raised some interesting issues that I didn't think of. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4):

Having single table with "type" field will be problematic when adding a new reference type that needs extra fields. Extending type field values is no problem but you would have to add columns to the table, fill default values for all current rows, etc.

Having separate tables would make it snap-easy to add new reference type (and automatically generate a form for it!) and searching wouldn't be any harder.

Answer (score 3):

Rails supports Single-Table inheritance and Polymorphic ActiveRecord types. I would suggest looking into these - ActiveRecord has some opinions on how the database should be structured.

Comment: I think this is the right idea.  The single table inheritance pattern is not Rails specific though.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to look ahead at what the SQL will look like for each of the solutions.  If you go through that excercise, then you'll find that putting everything in one table is the easiest to code and will probably lead to having the best performance.  It's easier to separate out the things you want from one table then it is to put things together from multiple tables.

Lets say my-one-big-table looks like this:

1 id
2 type
3 field-common-to-book-and-journal
4 field-specific-to-book
5 field-specific-to-journal

If I am just interested in books, I can create a view, or just plain sql, like this:

```
create view book as  
select id, field_common-to-book-and-journal, field-specific-to-book
from my-one-big-table
where type = 'book'
```

So, it's easy to simulate that the data is in separate tables when I want to.

But, if I start off by putting the data in seperate tables then I'll end up writing SQL like this:

```
select id, field-common-to-book-and-journal from books
union
select id, field-common-to-book-and-journal from journal-articles
union
.... etc, for each type
```

I don't know about other databases, but doing unions in SQL Server can be costly and there are restrictions when working with datatypes like ntext.

If you follow olavk's advice then your SQL for combining types in one query would end up looking like this:

```
select 
    common.id, 
    common.field-common-to-book-and-journal, 
    book.field-specific-to-book 
    journal.field-specific-to-journal
from common-table common
left outer join book-specific-table book on 
left outer join journal-specific-table journal on
... etc, for each type
```

I've worked with systems that used all three of these ways and by far, life is easier with the one big table.

Comment: I completely agree.

You can also add some constraints based on the type, to make columns mandatory for a particular type.  These alleviates the "everything is nullable" problem.

Comment: Mat:  How can one have contraints based on the type? Could that be done in the DB itself, or would it have to be controlled by the application?

Comment: I assume triggers that would reject inserting data with missing fields...

Comment: Surely it doesn't matter what the SQL looks like, you can put it into a view and work with it that way.

Comment: i think you mean 'inner join' and not union in the first query example?

Comment: jammus - if it were just a matter of looks, I'd agree, but just the other day I got stopped when trying to do a union with ntext...

Steven - I meant union.  If you kept the apples and oranges separtate, but you wanted to see all fruist, you need to union.

Comment: The multi-table solution is fine if your typical query only references attributes in the Common table.

Answer (score 2):

Alot of which would be best depends on how many different fields and the field sizes, you have a restriction on total row size (this can be ignored to some extent knowing that all fields will never all be filled in, but once you get to where the pages are too wide, the actually storage in the datbase ends up splitting the information making retrieval take longer.  So if the information is small and (this is important) not likely to change much (it would be a rare event to need to add new type of information not already considered), then the single table is the better route. If the table would be too wide or if it would be subject to many possible changes in the type of data that needs to be stored, then the spearate table would be a better approach although it will always be harder to query properly. If you often want to query multiple types of refernces at the same time, the large table is a more efficient approach.  If you usually only need to grab one at a time, you lose very little in terms of efficiency in having the joins.

If you choose to go with the one table route, make sure to put triggers on the table enforcing the data integrity rules for each type of data. You will need this because you can't rely on making the fields required.

One issue with having the separate tables is that you don't know until run time which of the tables you need to join to. This puts you in the realm of dynamic SQl which I'm not a fan of (for security and efficiency and maintenance reasons) or makes you do left joins to tables you may or may not need which is inefficient.

Another possiblity is to store the whole refence string in one larger field and use the user interface to check to make sure all required parts are there before concatinating the record and sending the information to the database. This would be the fastest to query by far for most queries which want all the information but would be a pain if you need to pull only some of the data out. It also relys on all data being inserted through the user interface which may or may not be the case for you. In all honesty, I can't see where you would need this information broken out separately, so this is the approach I'd probably take. But I don't know your business rules, so take that with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

There's another option: not one I'd fully endorse, but it's still another option:

Use three tables:

```
refs (id, title, refType)
-- title of the reference, and what type of reference it is

fieldDef (id, fieldName, refType, dataType)
-- name of the field, which reference types it applies to, and
-- what type of data is stored in these fields (ISDN number, date, etc)

fields (refId, fieldId, value)
-- where you actually add data to the references.
```

`refType` can be the type of reference, and if you make it an integer with values increase by powers of two (1, 2, 4, 8...) then they can be added together to make a bitmask in the fieldDef table.

**Pros**: very simple and extensible. If you come up with another type of reference, or a new field type for an existing reference type, it can be added in very quickly. Forms can be automatically generated for each reference type. All data is stored in one place, meaning you don't need to keep track of multiple schemas *(schemata?)* for [CRUD operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete).

**Cons**: this is the stuff that The Daily WTF is made on. Select statements can become very confusing and complicated. The database can't perform type-checking (eg: for dates, etc), and the generic "value" field will not be optimised for the data being stored in it.

Comment: Very interesting idea - but I can see how it leads to TheDailyWTF!

Comment: I can't tell you how costly our firm's decision to use an extreme version this in the early 2000's has been.

The resulting infrastructure was understood by perhaps 5 employees total.  The opportunity cost of simple things not getting done over multiple subsequent years has been HUGE!

Comment: Right - definitely won't be using this option then! Thanks for suggesting it though.

Comment: This is called Entity-Attribute-Value and it's a terrible idea.  And since the OP only has a few different subtypes, EAV is overkill.

Comment: On the contrary, I'd say that a system with only a few types is the best candidate for this method. I definitely wouldn't use it for anything much larger than a bibliography database, for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find the need to join tables particularly tedious; I'd take the more normalized approach here.

Answer (score 0):

one table and a "type" field would be my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about database normalization. Jeff Atwood wrote about it in his post [Maybe Normalizing Isn't Normal](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001152.html). It's a good read.

Comment: A good read maybe, but not particularly well-informed IMHO.

Comment: That's a horrible article! I don't recommend it at all.
Read the comments, or http://codeeleven.blogspot.com/2008/07/normalize-first.html

Answer (score 0):

What I've ended up doing in the past is using sub-categories: having a single table with all *common* fields inside it, and then several tables which can have a zero-or-one relationship to the "core" table.

The example below is similar to something we use "in the wild"; it basically builds a hierarchical data structure, where each node may be a folder or document:

```
CREATE TABLE Node (
  Id int identity primary key,
  ParentId int null references Node.ParentId,
  Name varchar(50) not null,
  Description varchar(max) null
)

CREATE TABLE Doc (
  Id int primary key references Node.Id,
  FileExtension char(3) not null,
  MimeType varchar(50) not null,
  ContentLength bigint not null,
  FilePathOnDisk varchar(255)
)

CREATE TABLE Folder (
  Id int primary key references Node.Id,
  ReadOnly bit not null
)
```

So your `GetFolder` sproc will do:

```
SELECT n.Id, n.ParentId, n.Name, n.Description, f.ReadOnly
FROM Node n 
JOIN Folder f ON n.Id = f.Id
WHERE f.Id = @Id
```

This translates quite nicely into class-based inheritance:

```
public class Folder : Node
{
  public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }
  ...etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olavk makes good points, and Corey gives a great detailed explanation. Reading Corey's info, though, gives me a conclusion of Olavk's answer. Keep in mind that depending on what you're doing with the information, you may end up 2-staging your query. Find the item, then for each reference, do a direct select on what was of interest.

Also consider the idea of storing everything in multiple tables and reading it from a single table. I do this for a large database I have where most of the queries need certain common information, but the full multiple table layout is still required. The inserts are slowed down a little by the triggers that they kick off (in my case, one per file where each file is responsible for up to a million rows inserted), but my later select queries can go from minutes to single digit seconds.

Data warehousing :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a discussion about these issues some time ago with my superior. Of course, I couldn't prove that "**hierarchical multi-table** approach" (see [olavk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200394/one-table-or-many#200406)) is better, but I felt it! I would always choose this method. One root table with all the fields that entities have in common, and 1-1 child tables with fields they don't have in common. If need this approach can be extended to more child tables, as long as business logic and other entities will have something out of it. That is, I don't think one needs to go overboard with this.

I'm also against creating **separate "child" tables** without the root table, where each table has a copy of the same fields. I think [Corey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200394/one-table-or-many#200671) suggests such an approach as an example of a bad multi-table model, and he criticizes it as well. I would like to add that having to write joins isn't the main issue with that. It isn't an issue at all, since most of database queries have many joins, and it's a normal thing. It's difficult creating relationships with other tables - you always need an Id and a TypeId to know which table links to it. In the case of a root table, you only need the Id.

Answer (score -1):

How about both? **Have your cake and eat it too!**

There's another option somewhere between the "one big table" and the "fully normalized" DB that really combines the best of both worlds: You can use something called [materialized views](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view), which are like views in that they are just as flexible and you query as many tables as needed, setting up all the joins etc., but they're also like tables in that the results are actually stored in a table.

The nice thing about this is that once you set this up and decide when it is to be refreshed (everytime one of the underlying table sis changes, or maybe just once per night) you don't have worry about it anymore. You can query the materialized view as if it were one big table (because it is), and performance will be fast (faster than using the select statement that is behind it). Most importantly, you don't have the headaches of maintaining data integrity. That's what the DB is there to handle.

If you don't have a DB that supports this out of the box, you can still use this idea by building a table out of the results of the view as a batch job each night.