# Single Table Inheritance find issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

I have the following 3 rails classes, which are all stored in one table, using rails' Single table inheritance.

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
class ThingTemplate < Template
class StockThingTemplate < ThingTemplate
```

If I have a `StockThingTemplate` with ID of `150` then I should logically be able to do this:

```
ThingTemplate.find(150)
=> #returns me the StockThingTemplate
```

And in fact this works, *sometimes*

When it works, it generates the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM templates WHERE (templates.`id` = 159) AND ( (templates.`type` = 'ThingTemplate') OR (templates.`type` = 'StockThingTemplate' ) )
```

When it doesn't work, it generates the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM templates WHERE (templates.`id` = 159) AND ( (templates.`type` = 'ThingTemplate') )
```

The sql is doing what it is supposed to, but the question is, WHY is it generating one set of SQL one time, and a different set another time. It's literally the exact same code.

Notes:

- I'm on rails 1.2
- I've already tried `require 'stock_thing_template'` in various places. It either has no effect, or causes other problems

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK. Turns out this is because rails doesn't see the entire inheritance hierarchy all the time. As it reloads all the items on every request, this explains the inconsistent behaviour (in some places a before_filter was probably causing the models to load, in other places maybe not).

It can be fixed by putting

```
require_dependency 'stock_thing_template'
```

at the top of all my controllers that reference those things.

[More info on the rails wiki](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/SingleTableInheritance) - go to the bottom of the page