# How many fields is 'too many' in a table?

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization

I have a coworker who is planning a database for a new app that will have several tables with over 30 fields each. Is this excessive? Maybe I'm just not enterprisey enough to understand.

Edit: Also, a lot of the fields are option-type sort of things (like on a request form, would you like your widget to be yellow or green, he has a field for 'colour' with an enum). It's quite likely that these will be added to or removed over time. I haven't really done database design and try to stay away from it myself, so maybe I'm being completely stupid, but surely there's a better way of doing this??

Answer (score 13):

The most obvious sign a table requires normalization that I've seen is fields ending with integers: CouponCode1, CouponCode2, CouponCode3.. you get the point. There will be exceptions to the rule as always though.

Comment: If you know any exception to this rule, please do not hesitate to developp. I have never met such an exception

Comment: The first that comes to mind would be something like an AddressLine column. I have no problem with AddressLine2 as a column name. Optionally, you could go with AdditionalAddressLine or something similar, but like I said, in this exception, I'm ok with it.

Comment: One of my colleagues always said "Thumb rule of Databases - Down Always Beats Across!"

Answer (score 12):

Database tables can legitimately have 30 or more fields in them.  What you need to look at is the normalization of the data and whether that normalization makes any sense.  It will normally change in the future, as well.  But, you want to try to minimize that.

For instance, if you have a table that has addresses in it, do you include the city, state, and zip code fields in that table?  Or, do you only include one field that "points" to a record in a separate table for those values?  The separate table would contain unique city, state, zip code combinations. The effect of splitting the data into two tables is a reduction in the amount of data stored (most likely but not absolute) but a bit of added complexity when you go to run queries against the database.  Now, you have to deal with 2 tables instead of just one.  But, on the bright side, it's much cleaner, and much smaller (likely).

The real answer is it's okay to leave the city-state-zip data in the address table in the right circumstances.  Or, you might want to "normalize" it out.  Both are okay.

Find a good database administrator and hire them short term to review the plan, if it's in the budget.  It will pay off in the long run.

Comment: Splitting the address into a separate table only makes sense if each address may be used more than once, but that's very unlikely unless you complicate your interface.  If each address is only used by one person, what you have done is vertical partitioning, not normalization.

Comment: I was referring to splitting the Zip,City,State into a separate table with a foreign key in the address table.  It is usually very likely multiple addresses will have one zip code associated with them and hence City and State.  (Each zip code afaik is only associated with a single city and state.)  Therefore, if your address table is huge, it could pay off to normalize the duplicated Zip, City and State data out into a separate table.

Comment: Zips can be associated with multiple city/states ... for instance my zip code (17402) is both "York, PA" and "Spry, PA"

Comment: @LuckyLindy That is interesting.  So, you would get a letter at that zip code no matter what city it is addressed to?  How about your +4 digits?

Answer (score 8):

Thirty fields is not too many - you just have to make sure your data is properly normalized (for which there are plenty of guides on the web).

Based on your edit where you specify that many columns will be option-type fields which may be added or deleted over time, I would suggest the following is a better idea.

```
BaseTable:
    Id
    NonOptionFields
OptionTable:
    Id
    OptionName
    OptionValue
```

Then you can tie all your options to the base record.  This will mean you won't have to be adding and deleting columns to tables all the time ly normalized way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 7):

Of course, the standard answer is **it depends**. A table with that many fields could actually make quite a lot of sense in some situations.

Think about the data you'll be storing in there. Is it likely that many of these fields will be NULL? What's the likelihood that these fields change (eg: more are added)?

If only certain fields apply to certain objects, perhaps think about putting those fields into another table. Alternatively, store just the basic, common fields in one table, and the extra information in another table, one row per field. As [I suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200394/one-table-or-many#200728) for [a different question (which might be helpful to you)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200394):

```
refs (id, title, refType)
-- title of the reference, and what type of reference it is

fieldDef (id, fieldName, refType, dataType)
-- name of the field, which reference types it applies to, and
-- what type of data is stored in these fields (ISDN number, date, etc)

fields (refId, fieldId, value)
-- where you actually add data to the references.
```

Note that this was **downvoted**, and probably with good reason. This is *an option*, not necessarily the best option, but it's still a workable method. The highest voted answer in the question I linked to there might be the best solution however.

---

Edit: since you say that it will be holding things like per-user settings (eg: widget colour), I'd actually recommend the method outlined above (with the three tables). Chances are that most people will leave things at the default, so you'll have a stack of useless information being stored. Please do read my answer in the other question because other readers have pointed out the shortcomings of this method.

Answer (score 4):

there is no arbitrary limit; enough to get the job done is a good rule of thumb

if you have a better db design, suggest it

if you want more detailed feedback, post the schema

Answer (score 4):

The term "too many" is a relative one... You shouldn't split a table only for the sake of reducing the number of fields, especially if in every query you're going to have to join them back together because they are essentially one-to-one relationships.  If the fields can be broken down into a separate, logical object then it would make sense.  For example instead of storing address fields on a customer table, they could be moved into a separate address table.  This is a crude example, but it illustrates my point.

Answer (score 3):

The number of fields is usually not a problem, but you want to make sure your database is correctly noralized.  [Third normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Third_normal_form) is a good start.

Comment: BCNF is better - and usually that which is in 3NF is also in BCNF.

Answer (score 3):

**OLTP**

From my experience of designing databases, there are very few tables in a normalized OLTP database that contain an insanely large number of columns.

IMO 30 columns is too many.

For me, no more than 10% of my OLTP tables have a large number(>10) of columns.

**OLAP**

Now if you're going to do a Dimensional / Reporting structure, some people may consider a 30 column table to be narrow.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to ask, "Are there too many fields in this table?"  Then there probably are.

Answer (score 1):

The guerilla's guide to normalization-by-default:

1. A table should have a primary key and at most one other column.
2. Break rule number 1 only as often as required.

Comment: rule number 1 is Darwen et al's 6NF, right? I've seen Darwen break it (http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/3010532.htm).

Answer (score 1):

There is no constraint on number of fields in database theory. A table can be limited to a primary key (even if this primary key is made of 2 fields), meaning that [Apocalisp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220613/how-many-fields-is-too-many-in-a-table#220731) is not very clear. At the opposit, a table can be made out of thousends of fields, as long as [normal form rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) are respected.

When groups of fields are obviously underused in a table, it can be smart to split this group of fields in another table with a 0-1 relation between the main table and the "sub" table.

For security reasons, it was also often proposed (a long time ago: i think it was my first book of relationnal databases, first published in 197?) to split the confidential infos in another table with the same 0-1 relation between main and sub. It was then possible to easily restrict user access to "sub" table. Such a configuration can now be easily managed through views.

Answer (score 0):

A tell-tale sign is just what you said. He has fields that should in theory be split out into a different table. Another giveaway is the presence of many optional fields.

I'd say that a course in database design is in order for your DB "Expert". And I'd suggest that you brush up on it as well...it can only help you grow in your career :)