# How to store multiple values of user in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I have table like below.

[image]

I want to store user roles like **admin,reader,writer**

How can I store the values in my table.

I searched in google and many results such as 2 types.

1. Storing values to a single **column name** as **user_roles** and store values with pipe (|) separated (same as above).
2. Storing values on another table like **user_roles** and store with foreign key of users.

Which of the above two method is better for development ?

Tell me the advantage and dis-advantage of both please...

Thanks & Regards

Comment: The second option - the 1st makes it much harder to query on the individual fields, for example if you wanted to show a list of all users with the role `writer`

Comment: A quick google for "database normalization" would be beneficial

Comment: It really depends on how big a system you are going to make, the smartest way would be to have a sperate table for permissions, but if your system is just a small one and not going to be expanded that much, then just save it in the same table.

Comment: @uruloke small projects get bigger, the opposite is rarely true

Comment: @Steve, But the size of database is become large due to this right ?

Comment: @Steve, some small project are just small projects. Sometimes you need a small project for like a month only, really depends on the use of the project

Comment: It will have negligible effect on db size, and disk space is dirt cheap, never consider that as a factor. If you envisage the db getting so large disk space is an issue, then yes you certainly need a properly normalized database. Again, option 1 is lazy and will bite you in the a**e later

Comment: @Steve, Sorry my think is not correctly. As you said in 1st comment, the query can take with LIKE statement of writter right. ? so the results are both in same.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons you want the second choice include, mainly

- Data Normalization Sanity
- Speedy use of indexes and not table scans
- Avoiding coding nightmares like `find_in_set()`

See [Junction Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619895) or associations tables (more simplified)

See [Nightmare Coding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34293589) without it (and slow performance as all get up).

Answer (score 0):

If you user is having more than one user roles, so definitely it will define as [**one to many**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521760/what-are-advantages-of-using-a-one-to-one-table-relationship-mysql) relationship.

So adding table with permutations alone with user Id is best option.  Cz one user can have many user roles.

---

this kind of combination never happens (one-to-one)

```
user A - admin
User B - writer
User C - reader
```

[image: 01]

Possible is  (one-to-many) or (many-to-one)

```
User A- Admin + reader
User B - reader + writer
user C - Admin + reader + writer
user D - Admin + writer
.....
```

[image: 02]

as well as read these too

1. [One to Many and Many to One Relationships - code.tutsplus.com](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561)
2. [One-to-many relationship - www.databaseprimer.com/](http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_1tox/)
3. [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: I want the reason for choosing the one to many relation other than first one. can you please tell me that..:)

Comment: Abdulla, you are not giving sound technical reasons. You can save data for one-to-many in a text file if you want. He is not asking how you can save data. He is asking what are the best practices and why. You are merely saying: "Data can be saved"

Comment: @Drew sorry i didnt get you

Comment: @JishadP did my answer helpfull?? if helpful accept + vote me